# custom rouge lexar in github pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, rouge

This might be a yes/no question, because it's still not clear to me what level of Jekyll customization is allowed in Github pages.  I've been tinkering a lot with code blocks and syntax highlighting and it seems since sometime in the last 9 months, the options for syntax highlighting in Github pages has been limited to rouge, which I think works pretty well.  The documentation on this is brief and I've been getting more details scattered around the web.  I was going to go to the trouble of making a custom lexar, following [the wiki instructions](https://github.com/jneen/rouge/wiki/Adding-a-new-lexer), but if there's nowhere to slot this into my Github page, maybe it isn't worth the trouble. (Actually making the lexar probably wouldn't take very long... I'd just be simplifying another one).

**My question is this**:  would my hypothetical custom lexar have to be implemented through a Jekyll plugin and thus not allowed on Github pages?  Or is there another way?  Thanks.